# Is there a reason to prefer openssl_pkey_get_private over loading it in memory?

Tags: php, security, openssl, php-openssl

I'm wondering why there are different ways to use the openssl functions in PHP:

- pass a key as string (e.g. load it using `file_get_contents()`, or store it in an env variable)
- pass a key file as a filename: `file:///var/keys/private_key`
- load the key using `openssl_pkey_get_private()` and then free it with `openssl_free_key()`

Is there a reason to prefer a specific method? Do the last solution better handle how the key is loaded/freed from memory (and if so, does that have a security impact)?

Comment: One of the big differences is that `openssl_pkey_get_private` accepts a passphrase to decrypt the key, which the other methods don't...

Comment: @deceze that's a good point, I didn't think of that! I don't use a passphrase so I didn't notice that difference. I wonder if it's the only one though, I'm mostly curious about possible security implications about how the keys are loaded.

Comment: I'd expect `file://..` and `openssl_pkey_get_private` to be similarly secure, since OpenSSL can control what is loaded when where. Passing the key as a string means PHP stored it in its memory and garbage collects it at some indeterminate point, which is potentially much less secure. However, I don't know the exact implementation details, this is only speculation.